# How can I detect share sheet open or closed in flutter programmatically

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, share, show-hide

In my page, there is a share button by using this share package.
[Share package](https://pub.dev/packages/share#:%7E:text=Import%20the%20library.&text=Then%20invoke%20the%20static%20share%20method%20anywhere%20in%20your%20Dart%20code.&text=The%20share%20method%20also%20takes,used%20when%20sharing%20to%20email.&text=To%20share%20one%20or%20multiple,anywhere%20in%20your%20Dart%20code.)

I want, when share sheet comes, the share button become hide, and when share sheet closed, share button wants to be show.. How can I implement this?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you add this?, Run this command:  $ flutter pub add flutter_share

Like what's in here = https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_share/install

Comment: Now I used flutter_share package. But how can I detect  share sheet close.

Answer (score 0):

instead using share package use [flutter_share](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_share) and use blow code for your purpose.

```
 await FlutterShare.share(title: ' ', text: ' ', linkUrl: your link, chooserTitle: your title).then((value){
//insert your code here for make btn disapeare
       print('flutter share now is open') });
```

Comment: Thanku for ur answer. Then How can I detect the share sheet closed.

Comment: Your welcome.Unfortunately i dont have any idea about recognizing closed state

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check `Share.shareWithResult` function which returns `ShareResult` object. This way you may detect if sheet was dismissed or a successful share took place.

Moreover, you may try WidgetsBindingObserver. When a share sheet is shown the app is in inactive state, when it is closed the app goes into resumed state.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyWidget> createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    switch (state) {
      case AppLifecycleState.resumed:
        print('sheet dismissed');
        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.inactive:
        print('sheet shown');
        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.paused:
      case AppLifecycleState.detached:
        break;
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```